# Scalar Product of Two Vectors Equals Product of Lengths by cosine of angle between them

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to understand a proof for this that I found online.

[image]

Let A $=$ vector $A$, B $=$ vector $B$, and C $=$ vector $C$ and $C=A-B$.

By the Law of Cosines: $c^2 = a^2 + b^2-2ab \text{cos} \theta$

So $||C||^2=||C||\cdot ||C||$

$=(A-B) \cdot (A-B)$

$=A^2 - A\cdot B - B\cdot A +B^2$

Since vectors have the property that they commute, $A\cdot B = B\cdot A$.

$C^2= A^2+B^2-2AB$

[image]

**How can we automatically assume that $\textbf{2AB = 2ABcos $\theta$}$?**

Comment: It's not "automatic". But you have two different ways of computing the length of $C$. In one of them, you get that the length is equal to $|A|^2+|B|^2 - 2(A\cdot B)$ (the one using vectors). In the other one, you get that the length of $C$ is $|A|^2+|B|^2 - 2|A||B|\cos(\theta)$ (the one using the law of cosines). Since the two must be equal (they are both equal to $|C|^2$), then $|A|^2+|B|^2 - 2(A\cdot B) = |A|^2+|B|^2 - 2|A||B|\cos(\theta)$. Cancelling and multiplying by $-1$ gives you the desired equality.

Comment: You need to be a lot more careful with your notation. The equality that you end up with is not $2AB=2AB\cos\theta$, but $2A\cdot B=2|A|\,|B|\cos\theta$, which says something very different from what you’ve written.